# Rails 4 paperclip avatar_file_name: nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

My user model added latest version of paperclip gem, I learn tutorials from paperclip wiki,

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" },    :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"
 validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/

 devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

User Controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
 def index
  @users = User.all
 end

 def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
 end

 def create
  @user = User.create(secure_params)
 end

 def update
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
   if @user.update_attributes(secure_params)
    redirect_to users_path, :notice => "User updated."
  else
   redirect_to users_path, :alert => "Unable to update user."
  end
 end

 def destroy
  user = User.find(params[:id])
  user.destroy
  redirect_to users_path, :notice => "User deleted."
 end

 private

 def secure_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:avater)
 end

end
```

Migration

```
class AddAvatarColumnsToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
 def self.up
  add_attachment :users, :avatar
 end

 def self.down
  remove_attachment :users, :avatar
 end
end
```

I working with simple_form in my **new.html.erb**

Sign up

```
<%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name),:html => {:multipart => true}) do |f| %>
 <%= f.error_notification %>

 <div class="form-inputs">
  <%= f.file_field :avatar %>
  <%= f.input :email, required: true %>
  <%= f.input :password, required: true %>
  <%= f.input :password_confirmation, required: true %>
 </div>

 <div class="form-actions">
  <%= f.button :submit, "Sign up" %>
 </div>
<% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

**gem file**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.1.1'
gem 'rails', '4.1.1'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc
gem 'spring',        group: :development



gem 'devise'
gem 'simple_form'
gem "paperclip", "~> 4.1"

group :development do
 gem 'better_errors'
 gem 'binding_of_caller', :platforms=>[:mri_21]
 gem 'quiet_assets'
 gem 'rails_layout'
end
```

When type rails c and **user=User.all**

```
avatar_file_name: nil, avatar_content_type: nil, avatar_file_size: nil, avatar_updated_at: nil
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you forget to change this to reflect your User object?

```
<%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name),:html => {:multipart => true}) do |f| %>
```

Comment: i update to `<%= simple_form_for @user,:html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>`, it's got avatar_file_name: nil, not working

Comment: You forgot to set your url, where is it going to go after user is created? Or you can just add a redirect_to on create action in your controller

Comment: `  def create
    @user = User.create(secure_params)
    @user.save
    render "show"
  end
` added to user controller. it all so not working

Comment: Do redirect_to user_url(@user) or whatever your route is for user show

Comment: Also cut and paste the message you're getting, either from your browser or the terminal

Comment: => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<User id: 41, email: "asdasdasd@see.xs", encrypted_password: "$2a$10$KieNpT3xN6mXde27hcB8iODINOIcl8s/v7r3UFEXk1Z...", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 1, current_sign_in_at: "2014-07-20 14:17:37", last_sign_in_at: "2014-07-20 14:17:37", current_sign_in_ip: "127.0.0.1", last_sign_in_ip: "127.0.0.1", created_at: "2014-07-20 14:17:37", updated_at: "2014-07-20 14:17:37", avatar_file_name: nil, avatar_content_type: nil, avatar_file_size: nil, avatar_updated_at: nil>]>

Comment: `  def create
    @user = User.new(secure_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User profile was successfully created.' }
      else
        format.html { render :index }
      end
    end
  end
` i updated it's all so not working

Comment: params.require(:user).permit(:avater) spelling mistake